# How handle multithreading on big-scale web scraping project?

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

I have a problem with my project. It involves downloading data from various websites.

For now it's tens of pages, but in the future it will be thousands of pages depending on the country. Each page has its own script.

To support these scripts, I created a main script that calls each subsequent script on a separate thread using the multi-threading library.

The script on the input has a path to the file with data already downloaded to the database, and on the output it gives the second file only with new data. At the moment, this solution was used only for 4 pages. It works as I assume. But I wonder what happens when these websites will be a few hundred or a few thousand?

I think I could create a separate main script depending on the country, but as a result, it would give at least several hundred pages (scripts) per country, so according to my logic, several hundred threads run at one time.

Does it have a chance to operate on such a number of websites? I opted for multithreading due to the large number of web content download operations.

Comment: You say you want to use threads, but why? IMO, a useful way to think about threads is to think about what each thread _waits_ for. When you explain the purpose of the thread to anybody, the first words out of your mouth always should be, "This thread waits for..., and then it..." If you can't immediately think of what thread X waits for, then either you are trying to implement some massive, parallel computation for which thread X is one of the workers, or else there's a good chance that you don't actually need to do X in its own thread.

Comment: Re, "according to my logic, several hundred threads run at one time" that's a clue that maybe you want a _[thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)_.  A thread pool has a blocking queue into which its clients can push _task_ objects. And, it has a collection of _worker threads_.  Each worker waits for a task to appear in the queue, then it performs the task, and then it goes back to wait for another. Instead of making thousands of threads, you make a queue that can hold thousands of tasks, and you make a few workers (no more than the number of CPUs) to perform the tasks.

Comment: My threads waits for response from webpage which I scrapping. I decided to use threads, because I want to make faster my extraction. When I don't use threads my script works like: script1 -> request, response, extract etc. After that, script2 -> request, response, extract etc. Now I do this x time faster, because in one time 4 threads working concurrently and the result is: script1, script2, script3, script4 -> request, response, extract etc. Thread pool sounds great, but what the difference between my idea and thread pool?

Comment: (1) Thread pool does not incur the overhead of creating and destroying a thread for each new task, and (2) Thread pool decouples the idea of "pending task" from "thread" (i.e., your program can have thousands of pending tasks, but you may choose to have only a few dozens of threads that are actually awaiting responses.)

Comment: Ok, sounds smart :) Now I have 2 scripts with 'ThreadPool' method. Works fine. But to execute these scripts I have 'main_script' which until today I have separate threads for each script. So in main_script I can use too 'ThreadPool' method? And then how looks like a cost of CPU and generally perfomance? Because in future I want have e.g. 100 scripts in main_script (e.g. max_workers = 5) and every script have too ThreadPool (e.g. max_workers=5), so in one time I have a 5x5 = 25 threads?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sounds smart :) Now I have 2 scripts with 'ThreadPool' method. Works fine. But to execute these scripts I have 'main_script' which until today I have separate threads for each script. So in main_script I can use too 'ThreadPool' method? And then how looks like a cost of CPU and generally perfomance? Because in future I want have e.g. 100 scripts in main_script (e.g. max_workers = 5) and every script have too ThreadPool (e.g. max_workers=5), so in one time I have a 5x5 = 25 threads?